# JQuery append() doesn't work from first call

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's the code with methods

```
var view = {
drawColorBoxes: function (colors) {
    var colorField = $('.colors');

    if (colorField.length <= 0) {
        $('.thumbnails').after('<ul class="colors"></ul>');
    }
    $.each(colors, function (color) {
        console.log(color);
        colorField.append('<li class="colorbox"></li>');
    });
},

    markSelected: function (color_id) {

    },
};
```

Once page has been loaded method `drawColorBoxes(colors)` stars work normally: it creates `<ul class="colors"></ul>`but after that at `$.each`
appending doesn't work.`console.log` shows data were recieved correctly. No exception appears, the method works fine when it is used later during the program.

Comment: Do you have a sample at JSFiddle?

Comment: try, `$(colors).each(function()....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is when the element is not found `colorField` is empty so append will not work.

Try this

```
var view = {
drawColorBoxes: function (colors) {
    var colorField = $('.colors');

    if (colorField.length <= 0) {
        $('.thumbnails').after('<ul class="colors"></ul>');
        colorField = $('.colors'); // You need to reassign/initialize colorField.
    }
    $.each(colors, function (color) {
        console.log(color);
        colorField.append('<li class="colorbox"></li>');
    });
},

    markSelected: function (color_id) {

    },
};
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. I'll mark the answer after 7 minutes expires